# Python Request.post for API Connection

Tags: python, api, web-services, authentication, python-requests

I posted few times before , but unfortunately I did not get any answer .

I am trying to connect to API for work purposes , so I can't share the actual URL . The authentication worked fine ,and I got the access token . The problem is , I need to go through csv file , read row by row , then make API call , then post the row, which has basically two values, to the URL

Below is my script to read the file and post the row to the URL:
*Note: I will also need to post the authentication token*

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

def check(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f_in:
        for index, row in df.iterrows():# this will go until the end of the file 
            url2 =''
            value1= row["value1"]
            value2= row["value2"]
            dic2 ={'value1':value1,'value2':value2}
            getdata = requests.post(url2, auth = authtoken, data = dic2)
            Error2 = response2.json()["ErrorCode"]
            if (Error2=='2004'):
                print("Authorization Token Value is Incorrect or Expired")
            elif (Error2=='2005'):
                print("Request Has Been Failed to Validate Data")
                
filename='test.csv'        
check(filename)
```

Currently , I get error that says:
**TypeError: 'str' object is not callable**

The error it is pointing to the below line of code:

check(filename)

I am not sure if posting the values to the URL API actually works or not because of this error.
Appreciate any support with this.

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear which line is throwing the error? "check(filename)" - this passes in a file name and then you read the text file to a variable called "f_in" and never use it. Perhaps change the method to "check()" and remove "with open(filename, 'r') as f_in". You don't want to have the same file open twice!

Comment: Also you have a variable "getdata", which is never used. And you're checking a variable "response2.json()" which is never assigned and will throw null error